# Unity, apk cannot be opened with AdMob

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have imported Google AdMob unitypackage (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v7.1.0), imported, resolved (Assets-External Dependancy Manager-Android Resolver-Resolve) and built a file .apk. My Android devices cannot open it. If I remove the folders ExternalDependancyManager, GoogleMobileAds and Plugins from the folder Assets, it will build correctly. What happens? Maybe, I should send you some files with text, but where are they?

Comment: In Editor everything works correctly

Comment: Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml: https://pastebin.com/t2gCBm0W

Comment: You should add the reason of the crash from the logcat in the question. Have you entered the App-ID of the project? Assets => GoogleMobileAds => Settings